# Django 1.11 - Add condition to field in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

## Problem

I have a model(Challenge) with a many to many relationship to User. The user model has a one to one relationship to Profile. Profile is used to store custom stuff about the user. In the Django admin, create form must only show Users that have the field is_partner True in their Profile model. Can I achieve this without creating another table to store partners?

## Model

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    partners = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
    details = models.TextField(max_length=512, default=None, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512, default=None, blank=True)
    documentation = models.TextField(max_length=512, default=None, blank=True)
    prize = models.TextField(max_length=512, default=None, blank=True)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom form that validates the logic you are mentioning in order to save or not the m2m relationship. according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: The problem is not after the form is submitted. When I create a challenge it lists all users and I need only users that have is_partner True in their profile model.

Comment: Oh, I see.. you may need to rewrite the query that lists that by overwriting it. I will update my answer hold on @TiagoMartins